# Why does PHP not have block-level scope?

Tags: php

The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) states that:

> Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope

I can't find any rationale for this architectural decision from the PHP designers. Why was PHP designed to only have local function-level scope, without block-level scope?

Comment: I don't get why people think this is an openion based question. Well - anything is openion-based in that level of thinking!

Answer (score 3):

Because variables in PHP are not explicitly declared. Block scope for variables *requires* variables to be declared; otherwise, constructions like:

```
if ($condition) {
    $a = 1;
} else {
    $a = 2;
}
print $a;
```

wouldn't work correctly, because the "definition" of `$a` would be local to the branch where the variable was first assigned to.

The same principle applies to other languages which use implicit variable declarations, like Python.

Comment: Could you expand on "implicit vs explicit variable declarations"? This answer seems to be saying "Block-level scoping isn't in PHP because _<example of block-scoped variable being printed outside of block>_ wouldn't work". Well yes, if PHP had block-level scoping, this example wouldn't work, but I can't help feeling like it's circular reasoning, rather than an underpinning rationale. Perhaps I don't fully grok what you're saying.

Comment: An explicit variable declaration would be like `var x` in Javascript, `int x` in C, or `my $x` in Perl -- a way of explicitly saying ahead of time that a variable exists, instead of calling it into existence by assigning a value to it.

Comment: That refers to the _type_ of the variable, though -- in C, it's just as invalid to declare a variable within a block, then try to use the variable outside of said block (as in your example). _If_ PHP had block-level scoping, it would be valid to pre-declare the variable (in your example): `$a; if ($cond) {...} else {...} print $a;`, even though PHP doesn't require a type on it's variables. I'm not sure that this answer fully addresses my hole in understanding

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what more we can add other than *that's how Rasmus designed it*. What was going through his mind at the time, I couldn't say.

You might be able to track down (or open up) some discussion about it on the PHP Internals mailing list, e.g. https://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg51630.html. As mentioned there, at this point it would be a huge BC-break, so it's unlikely to ever be implemented. But ultimately, it's a design decision like any other, and only the person who originally made it is going to be able to give you the "right" answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, block-level scoping is a possible enhancement that could be made to PHP in any future day  - if it is not too late now.

JS didn't support block-level scopes until ES6 was standardized. Probably same language evolution principle applies here too.

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't at all address my question, which is _why_ PHP is designed the way it is. But I appreciate the comment